Google font does not work when deploying React on Vercel
I imported google font into my React project both in both components and index.css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Monoton&family=Paytone+One&family=Ubuntu:wght@400;500;700&display=swap");
But the font does not work on deployed Vercel while it's working pretty well locally.
Also, I added google fonts into the head of my index.html, still not working.
Can anyone help?
